# How to convert a string Representation of a 2D numpy to an actual 2D numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

In a small project, I'm working on, I need to convert a 2D NumPy `str_array` represented as a **string**  back to its 2d array variable `array` form.
the `str_array` can be obtained as follows.

```
str_array=np.array2string(array, precision=4, separator=',',suppress_small=False)
```

in other words, I would like to find a way to implement a method `string2array` ?

Thanks

Comment: A string representation of a numpy array produced using `repr(array)` will potentially omit elements (replace with `...`) depending on the size of the array (similarly with `str(array)`). Obviously such a string is useless for recovering the full original array. For this reason, you might need to look for a different approach. What is your actual problem that requires you to do this?

Comment: Have you checked the NumPy documentation?

Comment: it is possible to display or the elements using 

import sys
np.set_printoptions(threshold=sys.maxsize)

the actual issue is that I'm trying to send a 2d array to from a web server (in cherrypy) to a client. 
in the client side I'm using the method in the requests module to get that 2d array.

Comment: I found another idea to work around this.
I transformed the 2d array into a  1d array. then received it as a string and used `numpy.fromstring`
`my_array =np.squeeze(np.fromstring(data,sep=',',count= 16000,dtype = np.uint8))`

 to get a 1d array from the received string. afterwards I transformed it into 2d array using  `array_2d= np.reshape(array_1d,(-1 ,second_dim))`.

but still, the result is that I'm getting a different 2d array than the original one.